# CSS the URL image is not covering the viewport

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am only getting a small piece of the image I set using background URL. I can see the image in the background but it's like zoom in. I have used background-size: cover, set the height and width to 100%and display: table; right now I don't know what else is there to do. Can anyone help me with this problem?

```css
.intro {
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 margin: auto;
 display: table;
 top: 0;
 background-size: cover;
 background:url(https://picstatio.com/download/3840x2160/c61c60/mountain-cliffs-nature-tree.jpg);
}
.intro .inner{
 display: table-cell;
 vertical-align: middle;
 width: 100%;
 max-width: none;
}
.content {
 max-width: 600px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 text-align: center;
}
.content h1 {
 font-family: "Yantramana";
 font-size: 600%;
 font-weight: 100;
 color: #E1EFE9;
 line-height: 70%;
}
.btn{
 font-family: "montserrat";
 font-size: 135%;
 font-weight: 400;
 color: #3A6168;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 text-decoration: none;
 border: solid #3A6168;
 padding: 10px 20px;
 border-radius: 9px;
 transition: all 0.7s;
}
.btn:hover {
 color: #CBDFD6;
 border: solid #CBDFD6;

}
/*--- Media Queries --*/
@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {

}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {

}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
 
}
```

```html
<head>
 <title>Full Screen Landing Page</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 <link href="css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <link href="css/waypoints.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <script src="js/jquery.waypoints.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="js/waypoints.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <section class="intro">
  <div class="inner">
   <div class="content">
    <section class="os-animation" data-os-animation="bounceInUp" data-os-animation-delay=".3s">
     <h1>Traveling.com</h1>
    </section>
    <section class="os-animation" data-os-animation="slideInLeft" data-os-animation-delay="0s">
     <a class="btn" href="#">Get Started</a>
   </div>
  </div>
 </section>
 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
 tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
 quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
 consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
 cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
 proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
 tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
 quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
 consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
 cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
 proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below are some changes to the intro class which would solve the problem. I added a min-height of 100vh. So it covers atleast 1 full viewport. Next I changed the height property to 600px, so even at a very small screen, the image is still behind the button. Furthermore I put the cover property behind the declaration of the url. Otherwise css doesn't know which background-image to cover. At last I recommend setting a background-position to center. So when the image is not fully displayed (cut off), it atleast shows the focus of the image.

```css
.intro {
 height: 600px;
 min-height: 100vh;
 width: 100%;
 margin: auto;
 display: table;
 top: 0;
 background:url(https://picstatio.com/download/3840x2160/c61c60/mountain-cliffs-nature-tree.jpg);
 background-size: cover;
 background-position: center;
}
.intro .inner{
 display: table-cell;
 vertical-align: middle;
 width: 100%;
 max-width: none;
}
.content {
 max-width: 600px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 text-align: center;
}
.content h1 {
 font-family: "Yantramana";
 font-size: 600%;
 font-weight: 100;
 color: #E1EFE9;
 line-height: 70%;
}
.btn{
 font-family: "montserrat";
 font-size: 135%;
 font-weight: 400;
 color: #3A6168;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 text-decoration: none;
 border: solid #3A6168;
 padding: 10px 20px;
 border-radius: 9px;
 transition: all 0.7s;
}
.btn:hover {
 color: #CBDFD6;
 border: solid #CBDFD6;

}
/*--- Media Queries --*/
@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {

}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {

}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
 
}
```

```html
<head>
 <title>Full Screen Landing Page</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 <link href="css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <link href="css/waypoints.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <script src="js/jquery.waypoints.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="js/waypoints.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <section class="intro">
  <div class="inner">
   <div class="content">
    <section class="os-animation" data-os-animation="bounceInUp" data-os-animation-delay=".3s">
     <h1>Traveling.com</h1>
    </section>
    <section class="os-animation" data-os-animation="slideInLeft" data-os-animation-delay="0s">
     <a class="btn" href="#">Get Started</a>
   </div>
  </div>
 </section>
 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
 tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
 quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
 consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
 cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
 proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
 tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
 quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
 consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
 cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
 proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.intro {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    background:url(https://picstatio.com/download/3840x2160/c61c60/mountain-cliffs-nature-tree.jpg)
    top center / 100% 100vh;
    display: table;
}
```

A good resource for this kind of stuff is [CSS tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/background/).